# VBA - Use standard instead of immediate printing to print word doc with Printout

Tags: vba, ms-access, printing

So basically I generate a word document from a ms access table with vba, and then I print it.
The code is the following:

```
With rs
    'ensure the recordset is populated
    If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then

        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        'objWord.Visible = True
        Set doc = objWord.Documents.Add
        doc.SaveAs CurrentProject.Path & "\report.doc"

        'not necessary but good abtitude
        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst

        While (Not .EOF)
            If Not IsNull(.Fields("REGIONE SOCIALE")) Then
                regioneSociale = .Fields("REGIONE SOCIALE").Value
                regioneSociale = UCase(regioneSociale)
            End If
            If Not IsNull(.Fields("INDIRIZZO")) Then
                INDIRIZZO = .Fields("INDIRIZZO").Value
            End If
            If Not IsNull(.Fields("CAP")) Then
                CAP = .Fields("CAP").Value
            End If
            If Not IsNull(.Fields("LOCALITÀ")) Then
                LOCALITA = .Fields("LOCALITÀ").Value
            End If
            If Not IsNull(.Fields("CODICE FISCALE")) Then
                codFiscale = .Fields("CODICE FISCALE").Value
            End If
            If Not IsNull(.Fields("CODICE STALLA")) Then
                codStalla = .Fields("CODICE STALLA").Value
            End If
            If Not IsNull(.Fields("NOTE")) Then
                NOTE = .Fields("NOTE").Value
            End If
            'Debug.Print regioneSociale & CAP & LOCALITA & codFiscale & codStalla & NOTE
            objWord.Selection.Font.Bold = True
            objWord.Selection.Font.Underline = True
            objWord.Selection.TypeText regioneSociale
            objWord.Selection.Font.Bold = False
            objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph

            objWord.Selection.Font.Italic = True
            objWord.Selection.TypeText "INDIRIZZO:"
            objWord.Selection.Font.Underline = False
            objWord.Selection.Font.Italic = False
            objWord.Selection.TypeText " " & INDIRIZZO
            objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph

            objWord.Selection.Font.Underline = True
            objWord.Selection.Font.Italic = True
            objWord.Selection.TypeText "LOCALITÀ:"
            objWord.Selection.Font.Underline = False
            objWord.Selection.Font.Italic = False
            objWord.Selection.TypeText " " & CAP & " " & LOCALITA
            objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph

            objWord.Selection.Font.Underline = True
            objWord.Selection.Font.Italic = True
            objWord.Selection.TypeText "CODICE FISCALE:"
            objWord.Selection.Font.Underline = False
            objWord.Selection.Font.Italic = False
            objWord.Selection.TypeText " " & codFiscale
            objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph

            objWord.Selection.Font.Underline = True
            objWord.Selection.Font.Italic = True
            objWord.Selection.TypeText "CODICE STALLA:"
            objWord.Selection.Font.Underline = False
            objWord.Selection.Font.Italic = False
            objWord.Selection.TypeText " " & codStalla
            objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph

            objWord.Selection.Font.Underline = True
            objWord.Selection.Font.Italic = True
            objWord.Selection.TypeText "NOTE:"
            objWord.Selection.Font.Underline = False
            objWord.Selection.Font.Italic = False
            objWord.Selection.TypeText " " & NOTE
            objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph

            objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
            .MoveNext
        Wend
     Else
        MsgBox "No record selected/empty table"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    .Close
End With

doc.Save
'this instruction gives immediate printing instead of the standard one...
doc.PrintOut , , , CurrentProject.Path & "\report.doc", , , , , , , True
doc.Close
```

The fact is that actually I'd like to give the user the possibility to change the printer or whatever else option before printing.

I'm talking about giving him *this view*[image]

before printing, instead of printing the document immediately.

Is it possible with vba?

Fragment of code where I use @Sergey 's advice:

```
End With
objWord.Dialogs(wdDialogFilePrint).Show
doc.Save
doc.Close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
doc.Activate 'just to make sure that user didn't select other document while generating
objWord.Dialogs(wdDialogFilePrint).Show
```

instead of doc.PrintOut

Also as a small code optimization I would suggest remove all If-s for fields data and modify word related section as follows:

```
        With objWord.Selection
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Underline = True
            .TypeText UCase(Nz(rs![REGIONE SOCIALE].Value, ""))
            .Font.Bold = False
            .TypeParagraph

            .Font.Italic = True
            .TypeText "INDIRIZZO:"
            .Font.Underline = False
            .Font.Italic = False
            .TypeText " " & Nz(rs!INDIRIZZO.Value, "")
            .TypeParagraph

            .............
        End With
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. However, `objWord.Dialogs(wdDialogFilePrint).Show` makes Access freeze (the code is kept in execution) and only after I terminate it by the process manager, it shows the print dialog window...There's something that's not working as expected

Comment: It works for me. Make sure that all Word processes are killed before execution. You can also show word window for debugging: `objWord.Visible=True`

Comment: Oh, now i got what's the error.The fact is that the print dialog window is related to the Word application. So if I don't previously open it, it basically waits for it to be opened. In fact, using `.Visible=True` works... but it opens a Word window, which I didn't want to...

Comment: It works also with hidden Word window. I suggested to show Word window for debugging.

Comment: could you please show me where did you put that fragment of code? I updated my question with the place where I put mine.

Comment: That's right place. Please try the test db I created: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ivid1leb9ngyqej/Database53.accdb?dl=0

Comment: I get the same problem! Access gets blocked until I either manually open Word or force Access to close... however, I'm using Office 2016, maybe it doesn't happen with other versions, I'll try with 2007. Anyway,thanks for the help. Actually you gave me the method I was looking for. Just a bit disappointed for this behavior

Comment: Just tried under 2016, worked fine for me. Delay before dialog opening is few seconds, it's normal